# Why does this code compile and run successfully it seems it should get an index out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I was reading through some java code in a project I was working on and came along a method with something to this effect in it.

```
Object[] objs = null;
objs[0] = str1;
objs[1] = obj1;
for(String str: strArray)
{
    objs[objs.length+1] = str;
}
```

I can't figure out what is going on here.  I was hoping someone could explain how this code is working to me, preferably on both a high level and the behind the scenes low level.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That should not run. objs[0] will give an error.

Are you sure you are running the correct version of the file?

Comment: No I just checked and it looks like I'm not running the correct version.  Thanks for your help I was afraid I'd missed some core functionality of Java when learning it.

Comment: What IDE are you using? If you're using Notepad... try Eclipse or Netbeans, they take care of a lot of these file issues for you.

Comment: I'm currently using Eclipse but being new to it and the CVS set up I probably just pulled down the wrong file.

Answer (score 6):

This has no hope of ever working in Java. I suspect that "something to this effect" is subtly different from the real code, if it seemed to be working. A few problems:

- It should obviously be throwing a `NullPointerException` on the second line when you try to dereference the variable
- `objs[objs.length+1]` doesn't extend an array, which appears to be the intention - arrays are a fixed size after allocation.
- Even if arrays *could* be extended, they're 0-based, so you'd actually want to extend them by setting `objs[objs.length]` - if this code worked, you'd end up with every other element being "missing"

Comment: A little faster and a lot more detailed than my answer. +1 for this and deleting mine.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that `objs` is `null` rather than allocated as an array.  The first line should be:

```
Object[] objs = new Object[2];  // array 2 elements long
```

Next, the "array length" is the total allocated size of the array, not the number of elements you inserted.  So in this example, `objs.length` is always `2`.

Therefore your loop is wrong too.

The correct code would be this:

```
Object[] objs = new Object[ strArray.length ];  // array of the right size.
for( int k = 0 ; k < strArray.length ; k++ )
{
    objs[k] = strArray[k];
}
```

Comment: He's asking why it's working when it looks like it clearly shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

- The code is syntactically correct
- It does not compile standalone, but with some additions, e.g.

  ```
  public class Test {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          String[] strArray = new String[]{"a","b","c","d","e","f"};
          Object obj1 = new Object();
          String str1 = "test";
          Object[] objs = null;
          objs[0] = str1;
          objs[1] = obj1;
          for(String str: strArray)
          {
              objs[objs.length+1] = str;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  it will, since it's correct Java then
- It will not run without errors (`NullPointerException` will occur on `objs[0] = str1`)

Answer (score 0):

The following code, which is your code with a couple fixups to make it comile throws a NullPointerException, as expected.

```
public class Crap
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    Object[] objs = null;
    objs[0] = "str1";
    objs[1] = new Object ();
    for(String str: new String [] { "str1", "str2" })
    {
        objs[objs.length+1] = str;
    }
  }
}


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Crap.main(Crap.java:6)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:90)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jason Cohen

What about the str1 and obj1 members that should also be stored in the objs array?